# Install for Personalization failure with error code as 0x6F00

Tags: installation, applet, javacard, globalplatform, personalization

I am trying to Install for Personalize an applet but when i send the command java card returns 0x6F00. 
I tried all possible options but it fails every time. Please provide help.

Install for load:
80E602001205a00000000008a000000003000000000000
9000
Load:
80E800006ec481f2010017decaffed020204000105a000000000076e75636c65757302002100170021000a000b0022000e0044000a000c00000052020800000000000001010004000b01020107a000000062010103000a0106a00000000001000806000e000000800300ff0007010000001c07
9000
80E800016e0044000110188c00007a05308f00013d8c0002181d0441181d258b00037a0322188b000460037a198b00052d03321a0425730014ffe2ffe20009198b00063219081f8b00077a08000a00000000000000000000050022000806800300010002000600000103800302038003030380
9000
80E88002190a0103800a0603800a0809000c000000080506040a07071307
9000
Package uploaded

Install and make selectable
80E60C002005A00000000006A0000000000106A00000000001010004C900EF000000000000
009000

Auth process
Select AID : 00a4040000
Select Respnose : 6f118408a000000003000000a5059f650201009000
hostCryptogram is :56673ab4d4ceb127
icvNextCommanda5fc175526901661
Ext Auth : 848200001056673ab4d4ceb127a1c4c4696a464158
Response : 9000
AUTHENTICATED
Current Authentiation Mode : PLAIN

INSTALL[for Personalization] 
cmd: 80E620000C000006A00000000001000000

Response: 6F00

Comment: Just to all who are trying this in JCOP,
INSTALL For Personalize command won't work in it.
Reason unknown to me. In case anyone achieve this in JCOP do let me know also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please implement org.globalplatform.Personalization interface in your applet then use processData(...) method to process install for perso data.

see here

https://github.com/myasnikovsg/TestICCApplet/blob/master/src/org/globalplatform/Personalization.java

check this question as well...
[Update: Personalization of Javacard Applet with GlobalPlatform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27186555/update-personalization-of-javacard-applet-with-globalplatform)

Comment: Hi @anurag 
Do we have any clarification on this processData(...) in terms of what commands it can receive? I tried to send commands apart from STORE_DATA and status word returned 0x6A88. 
Am i doing something wrong? I tried to look into specs but couldn't find any leads.